# Broadleaf site Template Customization

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Hi I Want To Add The Customized Templates to the Broadleaf site Where can i Add the Templates to The Broadleaf Site. I Have seen the layout.homepage.html and I want to add the other template to the clearance in Broadleaf What Can i do.

Please Help me to Solve The Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding new templates in the admin is not a feature available in the community version of Broadleaf. This is available in the enterprise version of Broadleaf.